# Proving a function of two orthogonal matrices is NND

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

> Let $X_{n\times p}$ and $Z_{n\times q}$ be two matrices such that $n>>p,q$. Prove
> $$(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)\ge (I-P_{X:Z})$$
> in Loewner order where $P_Y=Y(Y^TY)^-Y^T$ (Note the pseudo inverse)

I was able to reduce the problem to proving
$$Z_1 ((Z_1^T Z_1)^- - (Z_1^T Z_1 + Z_2^T Z_2)^-) Z_1^T$$
is Positive Semi Definite where $Z_1=(I-P_X)Z$ and $Z_2= P_XZ$

Spectral decomposition seems like the way to go but I can't really proceed.

Comment: What is $P_{X:Z}$?

Comment: @user1551 $X:Z$ is essentially binding the columns of $X$ and $Z$. So $P_{X:Z}$ means the projection matrix to the combined column space of $X$ and $Z$

Comment: What is NND ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie Non Negative Definite, same as positive semi definite

Comment: Where do we see **orthogonal** matrices mentionned in your title ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $Z_1^TZ_2=0$

Comment: Ah ! "orthogonal one to the other" ! This is not the classical use  where a matrix is orthogonal ... to itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal Y$ be the column space of the augmented matrix $Y=[X|Z]$. Every vector in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as $y+p$ for some $y\in\mathcal Y$ and $p\in\mathcal Y^\perp$. Since $(I-P_X)p=(I-P_Y)p=(I-P_Z)p=p$ and $(I-P_Y)y=0$, we have
\begin{aligned}
&\big\langle\left[(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)-(I-P_Y)\right](y+p),\ y+p\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle\left[(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)-(I-P_Y)\right]y,\ y+p\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle y,\,\left[(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)-(I-P_Y)\right](y+p)\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle y,\,\left[(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)-(I-P_Y)\right]y\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle y,\,(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)y\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle y,\,(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)^2(I-P_X)y\big\rangle\\
&=\big\langle (I-P_Z)(I-P_X)y,\,(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)y\big\rangle\\
&\ge0.
\end{aligned}
Hence $(I-P_X)(I-P_Z)(I-P_X)\ge(I-P_Y)$.